# CSS pseudoclass usage

Tags: html, css

I want to combine **a:link** and **a:visited** at once. What is best method?

I am thinking of **a:link+visited**. This doesn't work though! What to do then? What is the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a comma to apply the same CSS rules to multiple selectors.

`a:link, a:visited { ... }`